# How to disable TLS 1.0 on a linux server?

Tags: openssl, tls, protocol, vulnerabilities

I have run a PCI ASV scan by Comodo which reported that our server is supporting TLS 1.0. which it should not. See screenshot:

[image: Comodo TLS 1.0 vulnerabilities]

The server is from a GoGeek account at siteground. According to their support, TLS 1.0 is disabled by default on all servers and that the test is probably just a mistake on comodos end. Before wasting money on another scan, i tested the port 443 from another server using the nmap program:

```
root@server:/# nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.xxxxxxxxxx.com

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-23 17:21 CEST
Nmap scan report for www.xxxxxxxxxx.com (xxx.xx.xxx.xxx)
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Other addresses for www.xxxxxxxxxx.com (not scanned): xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 - strong
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.63 seconds
```

My questions:

1. Do i read correctly from the nmap report that TLS 1.0 is indeed supported?
2. Where/How do i disable TLS 1.0? I cannot/am not pro enough to find where to search for these sort of configs on this server where cannot not even find out the OS.
3. What does the error "Web accessible Backups" in the comodo report above mean?

uname -a gives:

```
Linux ukm16.siteground.biz 3.12.18-clouder0 #20 SMP Mon Feb 26 12:15:53 EET 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your Nmap scan report clearly indicates TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 connections all would be accepted by the server.  As for the way you configure the server to NOT connect with TLS 1.0 you would have to start by generating a new SSL certificate.

Comment: Ok. I will look into this now. I suppose that if there is no certificate present, no TLS security is applied at all? Can you tell me what you think that the vulnerability "Web accessible Backups" could mean?

Comment: That particular vulerability is indicating it was able to access your backups over an insecure HTTP connection.  If there is no certificate present, then your server supports NO encryption, which is unlikely the case.  If you don't know if that is the case, contact GoGeek support, or provide enough information for us to help you in another question.